# Python message: Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python

I get a Python message that says

> Process finished with exit code 0.

I do not see any error codes.  I made sure the path to my data source is correct. I checked in settings and show that the pandas and matplotlib libraries are installed.

The data source is list of mock IP address and code is suppose to print the list of IP address in descending order. As mentioned before, I only get the "Process finished with exit code 0."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Function to print the results
def printResults(message, value):
    print("\n\n")
    print(message)
    print()
    print(value)

    # set the file path
    # Note: you may have to change the path to file
    data = '/Users/Student1/Documents/Class_Dataset1.csv'

    # Read the file into the data frame
    nd = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', decimal='.', header=0)

    # Print the source IP frequencies
    printResults("Source IP", nd['Source'].value_counts())

    # Print the destination IP frequencies
    printResults("Destination IP", nd['Destination'].value_counts())

    # Print the Protocol Frequencies
    printResults("Protocol", nd['Protocol'].value_counts())
```

Comment: You never call your function, so it never gets executed.

Comment: That message came from whatever executed the process and it means that the process did not return an error code. In your case , the function was never called so python returns 0. Generally, well, it depends on the process. Some will explode massively but still return 0. Others will work perfectly and return non-zero because non-zero has a different meaning for that program.

Comment: Hello MarianD, the indentation fix made my project work.  I will later on research why not properly indent line of code especially below the definition of function.  I am guessing that  Python was still assuming I was defining the "Def printResults function"  Again thanks for your help.   Sincerely HotNCold.

Comment: @HotNCold, you're welcome. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Please correct your code  to be

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Function to print the results
def printResults(message, value):
    print("\n\n")
    print(message)
    print()
    print(value)


# set the file path
# Note: you may have to change the path to file
data = '/Users/Student1/Documents/Class_Dataset1.csv'

# Read the file into the data frame
nd = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', decimal='.', header=0)

# Print the source IP frequencies
printResults("Source IP", nd['Source'].value_counts())

# Print the destination IP frequencies
printResults("Destination IP", nd['Destination'].value_counts())

# Print the Protocol Frequencies
printResults("Protocol", nd['Protocol'].value_counts())
```

---

*The explanation:*

The only thing which I changed in your code is the **indentation** of your lines.

In your code all commands are part of your function definition, **which you never called,** so nothing was printed except the message

> Process finished with exit code 0.

(Every process finishes with some exit code, and exit code `0` in Python interpreter (as in almost all programs) means that it is OK.

And it **is** OK, indeed — Python has no chance to reveal what you *wanted* to do, if you in reality *did something other* but your code is still syntactically correct, without any run-time error.)

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 0 means the program ends successfully without any errors. If it were any other error numbers than 0, then it would be an error.

Also I think your code needs correct indentation as below, so that you can get your desired output instead of nothing:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Function to print the results
def printResults(message, value):
    print("\n\n")
    print(message)
    print()
    print(value)

# set the file path
# Note: you may have to change the path to file
data = '/Users/Student1/Documents/Class_Dataset1.csv'

# Read the file into the data frame
nd = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', decimal='.', header=0)

# Print the source IP frequencies
printResults("Source IP", nd['Source'].value_counts())

# Print the destination IP frequencies
printResults("Destination IP", nd['Destination'].value_counts())

# Print the Protocol Frequencies
printResults("Protocol", nd['Protocol'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be almost the same than the other's one... :-)

Comment: Seems like a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529498/7505395 which was postet roughly 20 minutes earlier.

Comment: Yes seems like that, but I did not copy that in fact :) I wrote my own answer, but own answer was mostly like another one's :) That's funny now for me :)

Comment: @Saeed, it's OK, it happens (to me, too). :-)

Comment: @MarianD I hope OP accepts my answer as best because I wrote less :)

Comment: Hello Saeed,  the indentation fix help me complete my project. Anyone else who provided suggestions or fix, I just wanted to thank everyone.  This has helped me alot. thanksHotNCold.

Answer (score 0):

Since you never call the function the code never runs and you only get `Process finished with exit code 0` (means that your Python code ran successfully).

Comment: I think the problem is not that OP got that output, rather it's ALL the output that they got. In other words, no useful results.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ok. Thanks for letting me know